# calculate downtime based on status values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to calculate downtime for service from data present in a table. (sql database)

table will contain data as follows:

```
service       Status       RecordedTime
   ID           ID

   1             2      2015-07-08 12:02:25.257
   1             3      2015-07-08 12:07:25.257
   1             0      2015-07-08 12:12:25.257
   1             4      2015-07-08 12:17:25.257
   1             3      2015-07-08 12:22:25.257
   2             0      2015-07-08 12:27:25.257
   2             2      2015-07-08 12:32:25.257
   2             4      2015-07-08 12:37:25.257
   1             0      2015-07-08 12:42:25.257
   1             3      2015-07-08 12:47:25.257
   2             0      2015-07-08 12:52:25.257
   2             1      2015-07-08 12:57:25.257
   2             2      2015-07-08 13:02:25.257
   2             3      2015-07-08 13:07:25.257
```

Multiple services exists , and their status are tracked , where 0,2 => down, 1,3,4 => up

I need to calculate the down time of specific service for a specific day/month/year

eg: based on the above table service "1" has the following data:

```
    service   Status       RecordedTime
    ID          ID
    1           0       2015-07-08 12:12:25.257
    1           4       2015-07-08 12:17:25.257
    1           0       2015-07-08 12:42:25.257
    1           3       2015-07-08 12:47:25.257
```

so the result for 1day would be

```
    Date          Service     downtime
           ID
    2015-07-08      1           10mins
    2015-07-08      2           1 hr
    ...
    2015-07-09      2           10mins
    2015-07-09      1           1 hr
```

Any ideas on how a query could be put together to achieve this?

i have the following query which makes them as common

```
select SIPTrunkID,0 as TrunkStatus,RecordTimeUtc 
from VoipGatewaySIPTrunkStats 
where ServiceProviderSIPTrunkStatus in (0,2)     
AND RecordTimeUtc BETWEEN (GetUTCDate() -1) AND GetUTCDate() 
AND SIPTrunkId = 1 

union 

(select SIPTrunkID,1 as TrunkStatus,RecordTimeUtc 
from VoipGatewaySIPTrunkStats 
where ServiceProviderSIPTrunkStatus not in (0,2) 
AND RecordTimeUtc BETWEEN (GetUTCDate() -1) AND GetUTCDate() AND SIPTrunkId = 1)
order by RecordTimeUtc
```

this i have done it for single trunk and yet to get the downtime values Once done it needs to be tuned further for all trunk each day

Comment: What database is this for?

Comment: database used is SQL database

Comment: I know, but which product - Oracle, MS Sqlserver, ???

Comment: how do you calculate downtime?multiple statuses with the same value exist for a serviceid.

Comment: The status are 0=>down , 1=> up, 2=>unknown,3=>warning,4=>critical so you we can consider 0,2 as down status , 1,3,4 as up status to calculate the downtime (i.e) if it is either 0/2 the service is said to be down, and it can be considered as up for statuses 1,3,4

Comment: It's great that you include sample data, but it would be much easier to understand if the example result was actually based on the data provided (which it can't be as there is no data for 9/7 and the sample doesn't add up to 1 hour for serviceid 2)

Comment: With a self-join or subquery.    Same strategy as a "running total", which there are many tutorials on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query, it uses cross apply to access the next uptime event for each down time event (except for consecutive down time events, where it counts from the earliest), and computes the difference.

```
select 
    date, 
    serviceid, 
    sum(datediff(minute, starttime, endtime )) downtime 
from (
    select 
       cast(t1.recordedtime as date) as date, 
       t1.serviceid, 
       min(t1.recordedtime) starttime, 
       ca.recordedtime endtime
    from your_table t1
    cross apply (
       select top 1 recordedtime
       from your_table
       where serviceid = t1.serviceid 
       and recordedtime > t1.recordedtime 
       and statusid in (1,3,4) 
       order by recordedtime
    ) ca
    where t1.statusid in (0,2)
    group by cast(t1.recordedtime as date), t1.serviceid, ca.RecordedTime
) a
group by date, serviceId;
```

With your sample data the result would be:

```
date        serviceid   downtime
2015-07-08  1           15
2015-07-08  2           20
```

which I believe is correct even though it does not match your sample result (but that doesn't seem to have any relation to the actual data).

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd101/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use LEAD to see the next record. Here is the correct query at last (thanks to jpw's helpful comments):

```
select
  thedate,
  serviceid,
  sum(datediff(minute, starttime, endtime))
from
(
  select 
    convert(date, recordedtime) as thedate, 
    serviceid,
    statusid,
    recordedtime as starttime,
    lead(recordedtime) over (partition by serviceid order by recordedtime) as endtime
  from your_table
) start_and_end
where statusid in (0,2)
group by thedate, serviceid;
```

In case a service is down from say 23:55 one day till 0:05 the other, the time will be assigned the start day.

Comment: This throws an error: _Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate._ so you would have to compute the diff in a derived table and move the aggregate to an outer query. There's another issue though: down time events can be followed by other down time events but lead will return the following no matter the statusId which makes the calculation invalid. I like the idea of using lead though.

Comment: @jpw: Thanks, I didn't know about this limitation and will edit my answer. As to consecutive downtime entries: That's no problem; they add up (from downtime 1 to downtime 2 plus from downtime 2 to uptime).

Comment: With your update query the down times comes to 40 for serviceid 1 and 35 for serviceid 2. Maybe that is correct, but looking at the source data it seems to be too high. I could have misinterpreted the question though.

Comment: No, it isn't. You are right again. It's because I limit the records to Status 0,2 to early. Will have to update again :-|